# Верхний и нижний cardMaxElevation должен отличаться от левого и правого в CardView

Tags: java, android, cardview

Коллеги, добрый день!

Есть список ListView, который состоит из элементов CardView. Необходимо, чтобы расстояния между разными CardView, а также до границ экрана совпадали. Для одного CardView это легко регулируется параметром cardMaxElevation ([см. дополнительно](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/cardview/)), но вот в списке получается, что верхний и нижний cardMaxElevation у разных CardView складываются и ширина получается в два раза толще, чем по краям (см. картинку).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу придумать, как это исправить. По идее, если задать верхний и нижний cardMaxElevation в два раза тоньше, чем левый и правый, то все будет хорошо.

PS. Как вариант, можно конечно отказаться от CardView ... но не хотелось бы.

Разметка ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:divider="#002aff"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Разметка CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff700">
```

Comment: Elevation не предназначен для отступов. Используйте для отступов margin\padding

Comment: Пробовал padding (в частности набор [contentPadding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/cardview/)), но это отступы от Content Area до края CardView. А мне надо от края CardView и далее ...

Comment: от края CardView - это margin

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо! Но для этого надо заключить CardView в Layout (например LinearLayout) и выставить margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо заключить CardView в Layout, далее для CardView добавить значения marginBottom, marginTop, marginLeft и marginRight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"

    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"

    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff700">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

В итоге, получатся одинаковые отступы:

[image]